# How to customize the type in Typewriter

Tags: c#, typescript, typewriter

The [Typewriter](http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/index.html) is generating date type in TypeScript for DateTime types in C#, I want to change it to "string", but not able to do so

here is what I tried in .tst

```
string TypeConverter(Type type){
    if(type.Name == "Month") return "string";
    return type.Name;
}
```

And then in latter section tried

```
//1
export class $Name {$Properties[
    public $Name: TypeConverter($Type);]
}

//2
export class $Name {$Properties[
    public $Name: TypeConverter;]
}

//3
export class $Name {$Properties[
    public $Name: $TypeConverter;]
}
```

But none of them are working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Custom methods are called like any other property using `$MethodName` using the current context as the parameter. So in your example there are two ways to solve the problem.

Change the parameter of the method to match the context:

```
${
    string TypeConverter(Parameter parameter)
    {  
        if(parameter.Type.Name == "Month")
            return "string";  
        return parameter.Type.Name;  
    }  
}  
export class $Name {$Properties[  
    public $Name: $TypeConverter;]  
}
```

Or, call the method from a `Type` context:

```
${
    string TypeConverter(Type type)
    {  
        if(type.Name == "Month")
            return "string";  
        return type.Name;  
    }  
}  
export class $Name {$Properties[  
    public $Name: $Type[$TypeConverter];]  
}
```

Comment: can you join the [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108182/typewriter), i have a question to ask